# How to create different language version of site from master site using SXA cloning?

Tags: sxa, item-clones

We have our master website in English built on SXA framework. We would like to create new website in German language. How can i use or modify SXA cloning script so that i can clone items from English version to German version in new website?

Comment: Do you also require that the data you have input in English be cloned into the German language?

Comment: If the default fall back language is set properly, the content would be rendered properly.

Comment: Yes, I would like to get default English content into German Language

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow two steps listed below.

1. Clone an SXA site (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/clone-an-sxa-site.html)

   a. In the Content Editor, right-click the site item, click Scripts, and click Clone Site.
   [image]

   b.In the Clone a Site dialog box, enter a name and click OK
2. Add a language version to an SXA site in the new cloned website.(https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-language-version-to-an-sxa-site.html)

   a. In the Content Editor, right-click the site item, click Scripts, and click Add Site Language.

   b. In the dialog box select the source language from which data is to be copied (english in your case) and target language is german language in your case
   [image]

Comment: It worked but i was looking for one click roll-out from Master website. I think that we can do it by calling both scripts one after another.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Add Language to the site is creating content item of the new language but there is no version is getting created for media.